# How to safely use a user-entered credentials in a crawler?

Tags: android, security, cryptography, secure-coding

I'm creating an App in which the user has to provide his credentials for a third party web site. My App uses this credentials to login in that website to perform some automatized tasks via Jsoup.

The problem I see is that when credentials are sent from the App to the Website, they could potentially be intercepted. Is there any way I can encrypt that data?

Credentials are not for a particularly critical service, it's nothing that deals with money or stuff like that, but I still do not want to expose passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's great that you want to keep your user's credentials safe. That's a good thing even if the service you're using is non-critical, since many users will typically re-use their passwords across sites.

As for what can be done, that will depend on what the service you are trying to use supports. The first question is whether the site uses HTTPS. You should definitely use it if possible.

Some sites also provide their own API's for interacting with them without going via their web-pages. I assume that may not be an option for you, since you are using JSoup, but if it is an option, look into what security features they provide that way.

If nothing else (or possibly in addition to anything else?), you might consider adding a section in your app with a paragraph with "recommendations for secure usage" or something along those lines. Urge your users to use a separate password for different sites, or at least for that specific site, to reduce risk. Be careful not to push it too much though - you want it to be a friendly reminder, and not a constant nagging.

Comment: The site uses HTTPS and doesn't provide an API. I think I if I not have another option, a good option would be put an WebView component in the app to allow user to sign in into website before the App executes the tasks.